# Calculate the variance of $Y=2X+7$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ have a mean of $4$ and variance of $4$. Let $Y=2X+7$. Calculate the variance of $Y$.

I know that the formula for variance is just $E[(X-\mu)^2]$ so we would have $E[(X-4)^2] = E[X^2-8X+16] = E[X^2]-8E[X]+16$. Since $E[X] = 4$ this comes out to $0$, but the solution says the result is supposed to be $16$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $E[X^2] \neq E[X]^2$

Comment: You must use $X$'s varaiance to calculate $E\left[X^2\right]$.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that $\text{Var}(aX+b) = \text{Var}(aX) = a^2\text{Var}(X)$ then $\text{Var}(Y) = 2^2\cdot 4 = 16$.

To see why $\text{Var}(aX) = a^2\text{Var}(X)$, just use the definition and linearity of $E$:
$$\text{Var}(aX) = E((aX)^2) - E(aX)^2 = E(a^2X^2) - (aE(X))^2 = a^2E(X^2) - a^2E(X)^2 = a^2(E(X^2)-E(X)^2) = a^2\text{Var}(X).$$

And to see why $\text{Var}(X+b) = \text{Var}(X)$, use the equivalent definition, and linearity of $E$:
$$\text{Var}(X+b) = E([X+b-E(X+b)]^2) = E([X+b-E(X)-b]^2) = E([X-E(X)]^2) = \text{Var}(X).$$